# sqfentity save() method doesn't update records

Tags: flutter

I am using sqfentity 2.3.0+5 package for my mobile app to store local data. In the documentation it says that save() method can be used for both updating and inserting but when I insert some data with save() method I can not update it after using again save() method.

Here is the example usage of it:

```
 await ClubData(
          id: data[i]['id'],
          isUnlocked: 0,
          currentLevel: 1,
          totalLevel: data[i]['players'].length,
          logoURL: data[i]['logoURL'],
          points: 0,
          name: data[i]['name'])
      .save();
```

Let's say that data[i]['players'].length is equal to 10 and I insert the data using save() method for the first time. Then data[i]['players'].length increases and I use the same method again but totalLevel doesn't update. What am I doing wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using an object constructor to set data, so sqflite doesn't understand that data has been changed.
Try to use this syntax:

```
final clubData = ClubData();
clubData.id = data[i]['id'],
clubData.isUnlocked= 0,
clubData.currentLevel= 1,
clubData.totalLevel= data[i]['players'].length,
clubData.logoURL= data[i]['logoURL'],
clubData.points= 0,
clubData.name= data[i]['name']
await clubData.save();
```

Or this:

```
await ClubData.withFields(data[i]['id'], 0, 1, data[i]['players'].length, data[i]['logoURL'], 0, data[i]['name']).save();
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I am sorry but both options did not update records. It doesn't work!